# How to insert data into oracle database from JTextfield?

Tags: java, oracle11g

I have a Swing application connected to an oracle database. I'm trying to insert the data input from the `JTextfields` into my database (when the 'save' button is clicked).
I have read similar posts and tried the following code but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I have the `ojdbc6.jar` file

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String lastName = txtlastName.getText(),
           firstName = txtlastName.getText(),
           ContactNumber = txtContactNumber.getText(),
           Email = txtEmail.getText();
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","username","pw");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        if(con!=null) {
            System.out.println("Success!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Failed!");
        }

        String sql = "Insert Into Customer values(CUSTIDSEQ.NEXTVAL,+'"+lastName+"','"+firstName+"','"+ContactNumber+"','"+Email+"')";
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int n=st.executeUpdate(sql);
        //System.out.println(n+" "+"record inserted");

        if (n==1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record inserted");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record not inserted");
        }

        con.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly ?

Comment: The data from the JTextfield wont insert in the database

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Comment: I get the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

*I have the ojdbc6.jar file

Comment: there should be an sql error. Insert Into Customer values(CUSTIDSEQ.NEXTVAL,**+**'"+lastName+"','"+firstName+"','"+ContactNumber+"','"+Email+"'). there is a + in your query itself, which shouldn't be there

Comment: Thanks, i have fixed my sql statement but still the data wont insert

Comment: i still get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your `jar` is not being taken into account in your project. Try to put it in your `lib` folder or in the `jre\lib\ext` folder of the Java version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

This line causes ClassNotFoundException, because you haven't placed **ojdbc14.jar** file in your lib folder of the project. or You haven't set the classpath of the required jar.